# Python and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

Have a problem.
Have this code:

```
response = bytearray(unichr(int(code)), 'UTF-8')
```

It returns byte array from code, where code = int

Need similar code for javascript.
I've tried:

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(1);
arr[0]=(+code).toString(16);
```

Tried

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(1);
arr[0]=String.fromCharCode(code);
```

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Decode a string? Encode a string?

Comment: i need to encode string

Comment: decode working like this: 
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);

  `var debugBytes = "";
  for(var i=0; i<bufView.byteLength; i++) {
    log('bufbyte: '+bufView[i]);
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Encoding and decoding strings is much easier if you are willing and able to use the [Encoding API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Encoding_API) as shown in this code example.

```js
//Encoding
var encoder = new TextEncoder();
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(encoder.encode("ABCダチヂ"));

//Output: [65, 66, 67, 227, 131, 128, 227, 131, 129, 227, 131, 130]
//         ^   ^   ^   ^              ^              ^
//         |   |   |   |              |              |
//
//         A   B   C   ダ             チ              ヂ
console.log(byteArray);

//Decoding
var decoder = new TextDecoder();
var decodedString = decoder.decode(byteArray);

//Output: "ABCダチヂ"
console.log(decodedString);
```